# Copying Specific Subfolder from Multiple Top Level Folders to a Network Path

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, copy

I have multiple top level folders (about 30) with one particular subfolder I need to copy to another network path (Windows10).

I am trying to see if there is a script or PowerShell command that will allow me to **copy the one subfolder from each of the 30 top-level folders to another location on the network**.

#### Example Scenario

I have top level folders labeled `Morning`, `Noon` and `Night`.

```
E:\
├───Morning
├───Night
└───Noon
```

Each of the top-level folder contains multiple subfolders, but I only need to copy the subfolder labeled **`Time`** from each.

```
E:\
├───Morning
│   └───FolderA
│       └───FolderB
│           └───FolderC
│               └───FolderXYZ
│                   └───FolderABC
│                       └───Time
├───Night
│   └───FolderA
│       └───FolderB
│           └───FolderC
│               └───FolderXYZ
│                   └───FolderABC
│                       └───Time
└────Noon
    └───FolderA
        └───FolderB
            └───FolderC
                └───FolderXYZ
                    └───FolderABC
                        └───Time
```

These need to copy to another path on the network, (e.g. `Morning\Time`, `Noon\Time` and `Night\Time` should be copied to folder on `X:\` called `TimeOfDay`).

```
X:\TimeOfDay
├───Morning
│   └───Time
├───Night
│   └───Time
└────Noon
    └───Time
```

I was wondering if **RoboCopy**, or **XCopy** or **Powershel**l could achieve such operations. I would deeply appreciate any advice or assistance.

Comment: If its once off than do it manually. Or use a file comparison tool such as `Beyond  Compare`. Writing and debugging a script is going to take longer

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser.  What do you want to copy inside in the destination directory TimeOfDay? The 3 directories Time or what is inside those directories? In both cases you will end up having the content of all directories in only one (you can overwrite files with the same names, just in `TimeOfDay` or in `TimeOfDay/Time`).

Comment: It is not enough `xcopy /E *\Time\* X:\TimeOfDay` in a normal CMD shell? Read about all the options and some differences among `copy`, `xcopy` and `robocopy` on internet (e.g. [from here](https://www.easeus.com/knowledge-center/copy-vs-xcopy-vs-robocopy.html))

Comment: This is certainly possible with PowerShell, have you taken a stab at searching and testing some PowerShell code for your need to try something on your own first? If so, [edit] and show that code which you are having trouble with not working as you expect it to work. From there, someone can probably give you a starting point to iron out the issue.  Start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3 but I have a few ideas if you can show what you have tried with PowerShell in particular.